# Extracting Autoencoder features from the hidden layer

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder

I have developed some code to apply Autoencoder on my dataset, in order to extract hidden features from it. I have a dataset that consists of 84 variables, and they have been normalised.

```
epochs = 10
batch_size = 128
lr = 0.008

# Convert Input and Output data to Tensors and create a TensorDataset 
input = torch.Tensor(input.to_numpy())  
output = torch.tensor(output.to_numpy())  
data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(input, output)

# Split to Train, Validate and Test sets using random_split   
number_rows = len(input)    # The size of our dataset or the number of rows in excel table.  

test_split = int(number_rows*0.3)  
train_split = number_rows - test_split
train_set, test_set = random_split(data, [train_split, test_split])   

# Create Dataloader to read the data within batch sizes and put into memory. 
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle = True) 
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=batch_size)
```

The model structure:

```
# Model structure
class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__()

        # Encoder
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(84, 128),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(64, 16),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(16, 2),
        )

        # Decoder
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2, 16),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(16, 64),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(64, 128),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(128, 84),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, inputs):
        codes = self.encoder(inputs)
        decoded = self.decoder(codes)

        return codes, decoded
```

Optimiser and Loss function

```
# Optimizer and loss function
model = AutoEncoder()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
```

The training steps:

```
# Train
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for data, labels in train_loader:
        inputs = data.view(-1, 84)

        # Forward
        codes, decoded = model(inputs)

        # Backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = loss_function(decoded, inputs)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    # Show progress
    print('[{}/{}] Loss:'.format(epoch+1, epochs), loss.item())
```

The Autoencoder model is saved as:

```
# Save
torch.save(model,'autoencoder.pth')
```

At this point, I would like to ask some help to understand how I could extract the features from the hidden layer. These features extracted from the hidden layer will be used in another classification algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place an hook to your model. And you can use this hook to extract features from any layer. However it is a lot easier if you don't use nn.Sequential because it combines the layer together and they act as one. I run your code using this function:

There is a function for Feature Extraction which basically takes model as an input and place a hook using index of layer.

```
class FE(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,model_instance, output_layers, *args):
    super().__init__(*args)
    self.output_layers = output_layers
  
    self.selected_out = OrderedDict()
 
    self.pretrained = model_instance
  
    self.fhooks = []
    print("model_instance._modules.keys():",model_instance._modules.keys())

    for i,l in enumerate(list(self.pretrained._modules.keys())):
        print("index:",i, ", keys:",l )
        if i in self.output_layers:
          
            
            print("------------------------ > Hook is placed output of :" , l )
           
            self.fhooks.append(getattr(self.pretrained,l).register_forward_hook(self.forward_hook(l)))

  def forward_hook(self,layer_name):
    def hook(module, input, output):
        self.selected_out[layer_name] = output
    return hook

  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.pretrained(x,None)
    return out, self.selected_out
```

And to use:

```
model_hooked=FE(model ,output_layers = [0])
```

> ```
> model_instance._modules.keys(): odict_keys(['encoder', 'decoder'])
>
> index: 0 , keys: encoder
>
> ------------------------ > Hook is placed output of : encoder
>
> index: 1 , keys: decoder
> ```

After placing the hook you can simply put data to new hooked model and it will output 2 values.First one is original output from last layer and second output will be the output from hooked layer

```
out, layerout = model_hooked(data_sample)
```

If you want to extract features from a loaders you can use this function:

```
def extract_features(FE ,layer_name, train_loader, test_loader):
  extracted_features=[]
  lbls=[]

  extracted_features_test=[]
  lbls_test=[]

  for data , target in train_loader:

    
    out, layerout = FE(data)
  
    a=layerout[layer_name]
  
    extracted_features.extend(a)
    lbls.extend(target)

  for data , target in test_loader:

        out, layerout = FE(data)
       
        a=layerout[layer_name]
        extracted_features_test.extend(a)
        lbls_test.extend(target)


  extracted_features = torch.stack(extracted_features)
  extracted_features_test = torch.stack(extracted_features_test)
  lbls = torch.stack(lbls)
  lbls_test = torch.stack(lbls_test)

  return extracted_features, lbls  ,extracted_features_test, lbls_test
```

And usage is like this :

```
Features_TRAINLOADER , lbls ,  Features_TESTLOADER, lbls_test  =extract_features(model_hooked, "encoder",  train_loader, test_loader)
```